K-means Clustering problem on Whitewine Dataset
I'm currently grappling with clustering a dataset called Whitewine in R programming language and comparing the effectiveness of clustering before and after applying Principal Component Analysis (PCA). Despite several attempts, I'm facing challenges as my data points are not clustering optimally even after applying PCA.
Before PCA: I performed outlier removal and employed z-score normalization to preprocess the dataset.
However, the clustering results were suboptimal, with noticeable overlap between clusters.
After PCA: Utilizing the prcomp function, I reduced the dimensionality of the dataset.
I'm providing the code each instance as well, for the benefit of those reading.
This is before PCA
# Summary statistics before outlier removal
summary(Whitewine_v6[, 1:11])

# Calculate the lower and upper bounds for each column
lower_bounds <- apply(Whitewine_v6[, 1:11], 2, function(x) quantile(x, 0.25) - 1.5 * IQR(x))
upper_bounds <- apply(Whitewine_v6[, 1:11], 2, function(x) quantile(x, 0.75) + 1.5 * IQR(x))

# Identify rows where any of the values in the first 11 columns fall outside the bounds
outliers <- apply(Whitewine_v6[, 1:11], 1, function(row) any(row < lower_bounds | row > upper_bounds))

# Subset the dataset to remove rows with outliers
Whitewine_clean <- Whitewine_v6[!outliers, ]

# Check the dimensions of the cleaned dataset
dim(Whitewine_clean)


#K-Means Clustering with k=2
#K-Means clustering investingate
set.seed(123)  
k_mean1<-kmeans(Whitewine_scaled, 2)

#Useful information about the cluster solution
#Cluster centers
k_mean1$centers
#Clusters
k_mean1$cluster

# Extract BSS and TSS
BSS <- k_mean1$betweenss
TSS <- k_mean1$totss

# Calculate WSS
WSS <- sum(k_mean1$withinss)

# Calculate Total WSS
Total_WSS <- k_mean1$tot.withinss

# Calculate BSS/TSS ratio
BSS_TSS_ratio <- BSS / TSS

# Print the results
cat("BSS:", BSS, "\n")
cat("TSS:", TSS, "\n")
cat("Total WSS:", WSS, "\n")
cat("BSS/TSS ratio:", BSS_TSS_ratio, "\n")

#Illustrate k-means clustering
fviz_cluster(k_mean1, Whitewine_scaled, geom="point", ellipse.type="convex", ggtheme=theme_light())

cluster_silhouette<-silhouette(k_mean1$cluster, dist(Whitewine_scaled))
fviz_silhouette(cluster_silhouette)


And this is after PCA
#New “transformed” dataset with chosen principal components as attributes
Whitewine_pca<-data.frame(processed_data$x[,1:7])


What I did in summary:
I cleaned and scaled my dataset (Whitewine) to prepare it for clustering. Then, I used Principal Component Analysis (PCA) to simplify the data. Even after these steps, my clusters didn't look distinct. I tried K-means(as this is the method specified in my project, I cannot use any other method), but the results didn't improve much. Now, I'm looking for advice on how to make my clusters clearer, especially after using PCA. As I said earlier, I can only use the K-means clustering method for my project. I determined the optimal number of clusters by using 4 methods (NbClust, Elbow method, Gap statistics, Silhouette).
Apologies in advance for not being able to provide the images directly.

Not sure what your question is here. Where did this data set come from, in order for someone to repeat your test? Based on the 2 variables plotted, I am not sure what you are expecting for clusters.  With 2 cluster, about half will go into each cluster.

I want to find a better way to remove the outliers in my dataset. I have tried the Tukey's method, but it's not working for my plots, as you can see, they are showing indefinite clusters.
the dataset can be obtained from here: https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/piyushagni5/white-wine-quality
